# Single numbers for accuracy and resolution for vector and raster data?

Tags: raster, vector, resolution, accuracy, gis-principle

This question is meant as a modelling question, not having to do with particular data formats. It was edited to better separate spatial accuracy and resolution (precision).

In order to make the spatial accuracy and precision of spatial data in different datasets comparable, it would be very useful to be able to express spatial accuracy and spatial resolution as single numbers. That number ideally would be usable for both raster and vector data, so that data sets using both types of data become comparable by spatial resolution and/or by spatial accuracy.

When accuracy in each dimension is the same, the numbers for each dimension could be coalesced into a single number. But in some cases accuracy is significantly different between dimensions. A common example is vertical accuracy being different from horizontal accuracy. So perhaps for accuracy it is necessary to have the possibility of using a single number for each dimension.

Ideally, the unit of the numbers should be clear and also allow easy comparison of different datasets. For example, the unit could be specified in the coordinate reference system, or be an SI unit (to allow direct comparisons without needing to look up and convert data).

Can such definitions be found for both types of data that make the numbers comparable?

Comment: I don't think you could get one number because there are at least 2 concepts involved- accuracy and precision. For a raster, the cell spacing indicates minimum spatial resolution but the value for each cell is a sample of the underlying data- e.g. a single value for elevation in a 90x90 m area. For a polygon, perhaps the 95th percentile confidence of every vertex to the true ground position might indicate precision. Clearly, the more vertices the better precision all else being equal. However, the entire polygon might be shifted and hence inaccurate.

Comment: Further to this, each measurement in a raster has its own inherent imprecision and inaccuracy, depending on how it is estimated.

Comment: I think it should be possible to separate accuracy and precision, if the principle of significant digits is used. Both raster and vector data are numeric, so for both types of data precision can be conveyed by always using only significant digits.

On the topic of raster values: I was asking about spatial accuracy only. So, for example,  the question does apply to height but not to temperature.

Comment: Yes, you can separate accuracy and precision but you asked for a metric that incorporates both. Note that you cannot establish accuracy without establishing precision first. Significant digits can introduce a concept known as false precision. In any case i) they are subjective unless a formal precision estimate has been made and ii) formats like shapefiles store coordinates as real numbers. You can control significant digits in a field but I don't think you can in the actual coordinate. Perhaps you can in the data format you are using. See below for a link that might assist your thoughts.

Comment: See this document for a good discussion of the concepts. https://docs.gbif.org/georeferencing-best-practices/1.0/en/

Comment: Thank you, Leigh. I realise now my question was conflating concepts that are better kept separate. I will edit the question to ask for a single number for accuracy and another for resolution/precision.

Comment: You are welcome @user1867448 It is a fascinating subject and I will follow with interest any further questions.